# Laravel Mix common chunk and vendor chunk

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm building a multipage app with Laravel v5.5 and using Laravel Mix v1.6.2 to compile my assets. I am defining an **entry point for each page**. I'm **extracting vendor modules** to a seperate vendor output chunk:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/page1.js', 'public/js')
.js('resources/assets/js/page2.js', 'public/js')
.extract('vue');
```

What I also want to accomplish is having **modules I've written, which are shared between multiple (2 or more) pages/entry-points, automatically extracted to a separate chunk** (e.g. commons.js). I can do that with this:

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
          name: "commons",
          filename: "js/commons.js",
          minChunks: 2
        })
    ]
});
```

But this doesn't work together with mix.extract(). I've seen the examples [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/common-chunk-and-vendor-chunk). But unsure of how to accomplish this in Laravel Mix.

Ideally the output would be something like:

```
js/
 |- page1.js
 |- page2.js
 |- commons.js
 |- vendor.js
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After having a look though the Laravel Mix source, I realised that the array provided to mix.js().extract() is just being used to create entry points and so rather than use extract() I just used custom config to specify entry points for my node_modules that are being used everywhere, with entry point name matching the chunk name.

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
let webpack = require('webpack');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/page1.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/assets/js/page2.js', 'public/js');

mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

mix.webpackConfig({
    entry: {
        vendor: [
            'vue',
            'axios',
            'lodash',
            'promise-polyfill',
            'setasap'
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            names: ["commons", "vendor"],
            filename: 'js/[name].js',
            minChunks: 2
        })
    ]
});
```

This results in 4 output files:

```
js/
 |- page1.js
 |- page2.js
 |- commons.js
 |- vendor.js
```

Comment: In the latest Laravel Mix, an [`.extract()`](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/4.1/extract) function is now available to help with this.

Comment: @TimVisée Somebody didn't read the first sentence of the answer